# Firebase notifications not working xamarin

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi guys I am trying to create push notifications using Firebase messaging, but my emulator pops up an error `Invalid service` all packages have been installed any tips?

[image]

Comment: Try running your code in a real device and see if your notifications show

Comment: Service_Invalid indicates that the emulator cant use Google play service. If you want use it in your emulator, you must configure it with Google APIs System Image. In your real device, make sure you have install the GooglePlay Service.

Comment: Thanks Alot! will check it out

Comment: Hi there yes the problem is resolved thank u !